# Validating with express Validator's .equals()

Tags: javascript, express, endpoint, express-validator

I'm trying to validate a request to an endpoint, Using express validator's .equals() to check if user type's input is equal to 'savings' or 'current'. But the equals() only picks the first value.

I'm tried using the || statement

```
 const creatAccount = [

    check('type').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Please specify account type'),

    check('type').equals('savings' || 'current').withMessage('Invalid Account Type: Account Type can be either "savings" or "current"'),

    check('initialDeposit').not().isEmpty().withMessage('specify a Initial Deposit'),

    (req, res, next) => {

      const errors = validationResult(req);

      const errMessages = [];

      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {

        errors.array().forEach((err) => {

          errMessages.push(err.msg);

        });
        return res.status(401).json({
          status: 401,
          error: errMessages,
        });
      }
      return next();
    },
  ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because

```
'savings' || 'current'
```

is first being resolved (as `'savings'`) and passed as a parameter to `.equals()`. Read more about how is that resolved [|| operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

There are a couple of options:

```
const message = 'Invalid Account Type: Account Type can be either "savings" or "current"';
check('type').equals('savings').withMessage(message);
check('type').equals('current').withMessage(message);
```

furthermore, you could move this to a function

```
const validateType = type => {
   const message = 'Invalid Account Type: Account Type can be either "savings" or "current"';
   check('type').equals(type).withMessage(message);
}
validateType('savings');
validateType('current');
```

**The recommended option**

Use [oneOf](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/check-api.html#oneofvalidationchains-message)

```
const { check, oneOf } = require('express-validator/check');
const message = 'Invalid Account Type: Account Type can be either "savings" or "current"';
const creatAccount = [

    check('type').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Please specify account type'),

    oneOf([
       check('type').equals('savings'),
       check('type').equals('current'),
     ], message),

    check('initialDeposit').not().isEmpty().withMessage('specify a Initial Deposit'),

    (req, res, next) => {

      const errors = validationResult(req);

      const errMessages = [];

      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {

        errors.array().forEach((err) => {

          errMessages.push(err.msg);

        });
        return res.status(401).json({
          status: 401,
          error: errMessages,
        });
      }
      return next();
    },
  ]
```

Comment: Using two statements doesn't work, one of each would fail, which would return an error. I would try the function

Comment: Im getting oneOf is not defined

Comment: be sure to add it to your require statements `const { check, oneOf } = require('express-validator/check');`

Comment: Thank You so much!! But the custom error message isnt working. I would look into it.

Comment: @Pelumi see updated answer. oneOf accepts the message as a second parameter, rather than having messages in each check. If this answer helped you be sure to upvote and properly set it as accepted answer :)

Comment: Thank You So much!!! works like slice bread. Can't thank you enough hehe.